# Autolayout issue in UITableviewcell Which has Uitableview as subview

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview, autolayout

I am very much new in Auto-layout.I have tried all my way and searched online but couldn't find proper answer . Here is what i am trying to do.. I have a UITableView1 with a customcell . Now in customcell I am having a UITableView2 as subview.

Here is my problem UITableView2 loads data properly with Automatically heights. But my UITableView1 cell height is not increasing as per UITableView2 height. Here is the image of my view which can make easy to understand. Please help me to solve this problem[image]

Comment: Try making the bottom anchor of the second tableView equal to the bottomAnchor of the first tableViewCell, and the height of the tableView2 greaterThanOrEqual to a constant. Then for the first tableViewCell heightForRowAt method, use tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension tableView.estimatedRowHeight = constant-here
And then in the heightForRow method of the tableView1, return UITableViewAutomaticDimension

Comment: Hi Thanks for quick response..Can you help me with an Example..I am not able to get this.

Comment: Are you using programmatic constraints or Storyboard constrains?

Comment: I am using story board..You can help me in any ways..

Comment: @Rahul for Tableview1, how are you determining the height? is the height fixed or have you set it to Automatic Dimension ?

Comment: @rakshith I am setting that Automatic Dimension..

Comment: In general, you *really* don't want to put a table view in a cell of a table view - the whole design of a table view is to allow rows to scroll. Instead, you're trying to set the height of the "inner" table view to match the number of rows. Much better idea is to create a custom view (like a custom cell, but just a view) and then - if you want more than one of those "rows" in a cell, put them in a Stack View

Comment: @DonMag..Initially I tried with that. But here here text and buttons both are dynamic and not able to find the textLabel height properly each scroll gives me different height of textLabel so that I was not able to set proper frame of buttons..This is the reason i choose to use table view instead.

Comment: @Rahul - can you show a screen-cap of how you *want* it to look?

Answer (score 0):

Okay basically:

First of all, you have to make your tableView1 have auto-resizing cells.
To do that, in your tableView1 class you need to add the following in your viewDidLoad() method:

```
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = constant-value-here
```

After that you need to add the following auto-layout constraints to your UITableViewCell subclass.

1. Create a method to call in your init method and call it setupCell()
2. In that method, add the following:

   `tableView2.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerXAnchor).isActive = true`
   `tableView2.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerYAnchor).isActive = true`
   `tableView2.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor, constant: -8).isActive = true`
   `tableView2.heightAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualTo: another-constant-value here).isActive = true`

Also make sure that `tableView2.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` is set to `false` and don't forget to call the setupCell method in the init method of your tableView subclass.

If something is unclear let me know.

Comment: "another-constant-value here"  which value we should put here.

Comment: A constant value, an approximate of what you think the tableView height should be

Comment: its not working..here is my sample project..https://github.com/Rahul63/Sample.git..can you please take look on it..and help me..

Comment: Alright give me about 2-3 hours and i'll have it fixed for you!

Comment: Check out this dummy project I made, you can set the height of the tableView and the cell will automatically resize to fit.
https://github.com/ibrahimchiha/TableView